# Can you help me translate this?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to buy a thermos for my girlfriend and this is inscribed on the side. What does it mean so I can impress her with the knowledge?

jk I just want to know whether it's meaningful or generic.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually question that asking for translation without showing a prior effort by the poster would be closed, but this poem needs some interpretation that's beyond beginner's ability

From right to left

天下賞花惜花人 - People in the world who enjoy and cherish flower

更添梅花一縷香 - Add one more fragrance from the plum flower

康尔 /Kāng'ěr/ (it is either the author's name or the brand name of the product)

I would interpret it as: 'one more beautiful thing for someone who enjoys and loves beautiful things'

According to this [post](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=104643571665105&story_fbid=134279185368210)

> 「天下賞花惜花人，更添梅花一縷香。」意思是因為賞花的人珍惜花，所以給花又增加了一縷清香

> Because there are people who enjoy and cherish flower, a lovely fragrance (a metaphor for good reputation) is added to flower

Comment: It is lovely, and I really admire your interpretation. Thank you so much. Sorry for abusing the forum; I really only came here for this.